# Iterating array - only array cells with values

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

What is the way to iterate over (Say a 10 cell) array in c# where only the first 4 are populated with values and avoid going through the remaining 6?

I can keep an int for index and modify it on every array add / remove operation,
but was wondering if c# has a built in (and efficient) function to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Iterations are fairly fast. Is this micro-optimization necessary?

Comment: yes it is, it's meant for high performance code, also i was not asking about the iteration speed, but how to avoid iterating a full array with a built in functionality.

Comment: I don't know if it's supported, but you also can create a sub array (it's can be cheap, with pointers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 performant options as far is as can tell

A for loop, the downside is you have to check the condition each iteration

```
for(var i = 0; ary[i] != null & i < length; i++)
{

}
```

However if this is really mission critical, You will have to keep a list (or index of your range), which slower on update, faster on iteration

If you want to squeze out a bit more performance, use `fixed` and `unsafe`

Comment: @TheGeneral, array index starts from 0. and your code will crash with IndexOutOfRangeException if array doesn't have `null` element

Comment: @ASh the type of the array wasnt specified, and typo fixed. the point was that you have to do a condition check each iteration or store the information. thanks for your comment

Comment: try `var ary = new string[]{"1","2","3"};`

Comment: I'm marking this is the accepted answer since it's actually answering my need of stopping the iterations when reaching a null / empty cell, which as i specified the array is populated at the indexed order, and it saves me the need to keep an index variable. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, a built in [TakeWhile](https://www.dotnetperls.com/take) method that you can use:

```
  var result = Array.TakeWhile(item => item != string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)); 

  foreach (int value in result)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(value);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With this I need to inject the condition, and create a sub collection to iterate, I was looking to iterate over the base object using something like Array.CellsWithValue

Comment: only with dictionary and a KeyValuePair, else, you can try and use the built in ForEach as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list and then convert it to an array

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(5);
int[] arr = list.ToArray();

int sum = 0;
foreach (int value in arr)
{
   sum += value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm actually looking to avoid additional overheads, lists and foreach are expensive. The most efficient way I have now is keeping an integer using as array index telling me the number of elements added so I'm iterating till that index, was just weird to me I count find a built in c# function which does the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this with the use of Lambda Expressions. 
I made a little console application. 
So it checks for nulls and length < 0 will be also a null and then it won't iterate

It won't crash with IndexOutOfRangeException, like the accepted answer

```
int?[] array = { 6, null, 4, 3, null, };
array.Where(t => t != null).ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Thomas, however I'm afraid that the code sample is not performance oriented, it's actually using the collection 3 times (in the where, foreach and when creating a new list using the ToList() statement. please see the answer I already accepted.

Comment: Yes the answer is more performant, but my answer avoids IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: The accepted answer was fixed to avoid this. Thanks anyway.